# Tkinter and gettext is not work together on Python because of "_" usage

Tags: python-3.x

I am creating a multilanguage GUI with Tkinter and gettext modules on python. It is the code.

```
Label(login_screen, text=_("Username * ")).grid(columnspan=2)

username_login_entry = Entry(login_screen, textvariable=username_verify)
username_login_entry.grid(columnspan=2 , padx = 5, pady =5)

Label(login_screen, text=_("Password * ")).grid(columnspan=2)

password_login_entry = Entry(login_screen, textvariable=password_verify, show= '*')
password_login_entry.grid(columnspan=2, padx = 5, pady =5)

Button(login_screen, text=_("Login"), width=10, height=1, command = login_verify).grid(row = 5 , column = 0 , padx = 5, pady =5 )

Button(login_screen, text=_("Sign up"), width=10, height=1, command=new_user).grid(row = 5 , column = 1 , padx = 5, pady =5)
```

There is an error like in the below.

```
File "C:/Users/ezgis/Desktop/Inv/main.py", line 24, in login
login_screen.title(_("Login"))
NameError: name '_' is not defined
```

But I need to use "_" to change the fields to other languages. Can u help me?

Comment: Why are you using the underscore? What do you intend your input to `title()` to be?

Comment: I am using underscore because for the gettext module it is necessary to know which strings will translate to the other language. In the link, you can see the usage of it. https://docs.python.org/3/library/gettext.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After importing `gettext`, ensure you include the line:

```
_ = gettext.gettext
```